# How to save samples of type HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass in HealthKit in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, healthkit

I try to get authorization to save samples of type `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass:` and `HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth`

My code is,

```
NSArray *readTypes = @[[HKObjectType   
    characteristicTypeForIdentifier:HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth]];

NSArray *writeTypes = @[[HKObjectType 
    quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass]];

[self.healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:[NSSet setWithArray:readTypes]
    readTypes:[NSSet setWithArray:writeTypes] completion:nil];
```

when I'm running this code, I get the exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Authorization to share the following types is disallowed: HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth’.

i am running in `iOS 9.2` and `Xcode 7.2`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation of [requestAuthorizationToShareTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKHealthStore_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKHealthStore/requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:completion:)

typesToShare includes a set containing the data types you want to share. This set can contain any concrete subclass of the `HKSampleType` class

typesToRead includes a set containing the data types you want to read. This set can contain any concrete subclass of the `HKObjectType` class

so in your case,

```
NSArray *readTypes = @[[HKObjectType   
    characteristicTypeForIdentifier:HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth]];

NSArray *writeTypes = @[[HKObjectType 
    quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass]];
```

either try,

```
[self.healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:[NSSet setWithArray:writeTypes]
    readTypes:[NSSet setWithArray:readTypes] completion:nil];
```

or try

```
NSArray *readTypes = @[[HKObjectType   
    characteristicTypeForIdentifier:HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth], [HKObjectType 
    quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass]];
[self.healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:nil
    readTypes:[NSSet setWithArray:readTypes] completion:nil];
```